# Latex to html conversion - ! Undefined control sequence

Tags: errors

I currently installed tex4ht and tried to convert tex to html by using the command:

```
 mzlatex test1_testing.tex "html,mathplayer"
```

**In input tex file contains the below line:**

```
 \figsupp[Histological and electrophysiological identification of SC layers.]
```

**\figsupp is defined in the xxxx.cls file as like below:**

```
\newcommand{\figsupp}[3][]{%
    \refstepcounter{figsupp}%
    {%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{none}{}{%
      \small\textbf{Figure~\thefigure--Figure supplement \arabic{figsupp}.} \ifstrempty{#1}{#2}{#1}}}\par
    \addtostream{suppinfo}{%
      \noindent\protect\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \protect #3\noexpand\par
      \textbf{Figure \thefigure--Figure supplement \arabic{figsupp}.} #2\noexpand\par
      \vskip8pt
      \protect\end{minipage}
      \vskip16pt
    }
```

---

**when I run the command:**
mzlatex test1_testing.tex "html,mathplayer"

I get the below error:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.118  \figsupp
               {Top: representative chaperone/rhodanese complex in the fully...
Note: Please suggest how to use custom class files and how to resolve the above error

Also get character missing and shown as NUL in notepad++

[image]

Comment: Please add a minimal working example, it is not possible to fix it without more details

Comment: As per your comment, I edited.. Please help to resolve

Answer (score 1):

So here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{newfile}
\newoutputstream{output}
\newoutputstream{suppinfo}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.suppinfo}{suppinfo}
\newcounter{figsupp}

\newcommand{\figsupp}[3][]{%
  \refstepcounter{figsupp}%
  {%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{none}{}{%
    \small\textbf{Figure~\thefigure--Figure supplement \arabic{figsupp}.} \ifstrempty{#1}{#2}{#1}}}\par
      \addtostream{suppinfo}{%
      \noindent\protect\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \protect #3\noexpand\par
        \textbf{Figure \thefigure--Figure supplement \arabic{figsupp}.} #2\noexpand\par
        \vskip8pt
      \protect\end{minipage}
      \vskip16pt
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image.png}
  \figsupp[Histological and electrophysiological identification of SC layers.]{hello}{world}
\end{figure}
Quantified
\end{document}
```

I've compiled it using command:

```
make4ht -l sample.tex "mathml,mathjax"
```

It uses `LuaTeX` for the conversion, as you seem to use OpenType fonts anyway. 
Please don't use `mzlatex` and similar scripts, they are outdated and don't support LuaTeX or XeTeX.

The document compiles without errors:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the same, but i get the following error: Unsupported font        [OpenSans-Bold.ttf]:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;
+tlig;+liga;+tnum;+lnum;
Unsupported font        [OpenSans-Regular.ttf]:mode=node;script=latn;language=df
lt;+tlig;+liga;+tnum;+lnum;
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `tex4ht.env'
--- error --- Illegal storage address
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command tex4ht returned exit code 1

Comment: @Saravanan do you use up-to date TeX distribution? I don't get any errors in teX Live 2020

Comment: Thanks! Once updated my TeX distribution. It works

Comment: @Saravanan that's great! There was lot of development in LaTeX recently, so it can happen that some things break due to this. We usually fix the issues quickly, so it is important to keep your distribution up-to date.